# "Backspace" a character in STDOUT in Java?

Tags: java, stdout, stdin

I'm building a simple application that basically does the following:

```
logger.debug("Server start.");
server.start();
System.in.read();
logger.debug("Server stop.");
server.stop();
```

What I'd really like to do is to completely obliterate whatever character the user types in, whether it's a line break or a letter. I simply want the log output to look like this:

```
Server start
Server stop
```

...rather than like this:

```
Server start

Server stop
```

if the user hit "ENTER" at the prompt. How can I make this happen? How can I eat all typed characters, then shut down my server as per the example above?

Comment: Java can send whatever it wants to STDOUT. The real question is: what does the thing handling STDOUT do with it (how is it already setup)? (Does it support VT100 escape codes or "ANSI.SYS" codes or ...?) One could find that information out and send the right escape sequences manually ... or use a library that tries to get it all right magically.

Comment: This question is unclear.  Are you talking about the characters that are echoed to the console, characters displayed in a GUI or characters that are written to a log file.  These are different things, and require different solutions.

Comment: My apologies, I'm talking about terminal output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in pure Java because manipulating characters in a terminal window must be done by a terminal controlling library (such as [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29)).  The core Java APIs don't provide this sort of functionality but there might be JNI wrappers (such as [Java Curses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/)).

Comment: In principle you only need to send the right information to System.out (or whatever stream is connected to the terminal). The problem is only that different terminals will react differently, and you'll have to somehow get the type of terminal.  The native libraries (at least on unix-like systems) usually do not much else than abstracting these terminal differences, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the input stream for system.in to something else, the input will redirect to something else other than the console.  That should "obliterate" that line.

Link: download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream)

It says 5.0 but method should still exist in 6.

In hindsight, I'm not sure this will work.  Don't have Java open in front of me, so not sure if this will work.

**Edit** if you have control of the logger, can you prevent it from printing a new line character?  That would be easiest.

Comment: Just as an FYI, if you are browsing in the JavaDocs on their site, you can generally replace the version number with the one you want. It's a lot easier with version 6: [http://download.oracle.com/javase/**6**/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream))

Comment: Replacing `System.in` only changes from where your application can read, it does change nothing about what the user can type in.